# How can I make BeautifulSoup using `select` html element with row color <tr bgcolor="#EFEFEF">

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

There are 28 matches in a table with class `contentTable`, but I am getting len(trElems) =0; while running this code. How can I get all 28 matches?
Thanks in advance.

```
>>import bs4, requests
>>soup = requests.get('http://www.websitelink.com')
>>>soupCode = bs4.BeautifulSoup(soup.text)
>>>trElems = soupCode.select('.content_table tr bgcolor')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bgcolor` is an attribute,so you need to filter with attribute,try with below:

```
trElems = soupCode.findAll(".content_table tr",{"bgcolor":"#EFEFEF"})
```

More detail of `findAll` can be found at [BeutifulSoup documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html#The%20basic%20find%20method:%20findAll%28name,%20attrs,%20recursive,%20text,%20limit,%20**kwargs%29)